# How to configure VisualVM Eclipse plugin with Eclipse openjdk

Tags: java, eclipse, visualvm

I am using Eclipse 2022-03, which uses the openjdk that comes with.  I installed the VisualVM Eclipse plugin from the VisualVM web site and configured that.  By default, the VisualVM launch configuration sets the JDK Home path to the openjdk in the .p2 repository.  On launch, VisualVM says the JDK Home path is not set (at least not correctly).  How do I get recent versions of the VisualVM plugin to work with recent versions of Eclipse and openjdk?

Comment: Please show the launch configuration with the exact JDK Home path you have and the exact error message you get, both as text. Please note, "recent versions" is not a proper version number (see _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0)
Build id: 20220310-1457

visualvm_launcher_u3_eclipse downloaded 4/17/2023

In the VisualVM Configuration preferences:

VisualVM Executable: `C:\Users\myname\Documents\DevApps\Installs\visualvm_215\bin\visualvm.exe`

JDK Home: `C:\Users\myname\\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.6.v20230204-1729`

On launch, the popup says:

You are trying to launch VisualVM using an unsupported JDK.

Use `Window\Preferences\Run/Debug\Launching\VisualVM Configuration` to set the VisualVM JDK_HOME